# A connect to Computer B using SSH. How to launch firefox in Computer A?

Tags: ssh, firefox

I connect to computer B this way.

```
ssh -X computerB@10.2.1.123
```

Now when I launch firefox it launches on computerB

```
firefox
```

How do i make it launch in computer A? Because I dont have access to the screen of computer B.

Comment: You should install `lynx` with `sudo apt install lynx` a command line browser for linux.

Comment: @AkibAzmain Why install `lynx` when you want to use firefox? That makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: What is the reason you are running Firefox on the remote computer? Did you consider using socks proxy over ssh? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/469582/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-socks-proxy-that-tunnels-traffic-through-ssh

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.